# Java: Efficient way to search for multiple objects in a large list

Tags: java, xml, csv, arraylist

Im working on a java code to read and retreive specific data from a XML file and then upload it to a Database, the data I need to retreive is determined by a CSV that has a name and the complete path of the node within the XML file, aftear reading the `CSV` file Im storing all the paths in a `List` of `String`, The CSV file looks like so:

**XMLPaths.CSV**

```
XMLDate,Invoice/cbc:IssueDate
XMLSupplierName,Invoice/cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyLegalEntity/cbc:RegistrationName
XMLRUC,Invoice/cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cbc:CustomerAssignedAccountID
XMLDocType,Invoice/cbc:InvoiceTypeCode
XMLID,Invoice/cbc:ID
XMLCustomerID,Invoice/cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cbc:CustomerAssignedAccountID
XMLCustomerName,Invoice/cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyLegalEntity/cbc:RegistrationName
XMLMonetaryTotal,Invoice/cac:LegalMonetaryTotal/cbc:PayableAmount/
XMLCurrency,Invoice/cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode
```

currently im reading the XML file generically using `DOM` and im storing the data from all the nodes in custom class called `XMLData` and then adding each `XMLData` object to a `List` of `XMLData` objects, The `Tag` contains the complete path of the node just like the ones defined in the `CSV` file

**XMLData.java**

```
public class XMLData {

    public String Tag;
    public String Value;

    public XMLData() {        
    Tag= "";
    Value= "";
    }
    }
```

after that I need to select the elements defined by the `CSV` file from the `List` of `XMLData` and upload them to a `database`, the easiest solution would be to search for each item in the list like so:

```
       List <XMLData> XMLDataList = GetData();
       List <String> listOfPaths = GetPaths();

            for (String Path : listOfPaths) {
                for (XMLData Aux: XMLDataList){
                    if (Aux.Tag.equals(Path))
                        UploadToDB(Aux);
                }
            }
```

But I think this would be very inneficient specially if the `List` of `Paths` and the `List` of `XMLData` are very large, is there a more efficient way to do this search ?

Comment: Have you tried [HashMaps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instead of lists? You should initialize according to the size they're going to get so it doesn't need to resize automatically as you add stuff.

Comment: The code is quite confusing to read at first as it doesn't follow the Java naming conventions. Method names and variables should begin with a lower case character.

Comment: DOM is pretty slow in my experience.  Stax is faster but more primitive to work with.  If you really need to use XPath though I don't know of a way to do it directly without DOM.  XPath might be faster though than what you have now, which appears to be just rolling your own simple search.

Comment: @GermanC I have never used HashMaps, I just saw some examples and im guessing the Key of the map would be the `Tag` and the value would be the `value`, I guess searching using `map.get( )` must be way faster that searching using a for, right ?

Comment: @algorhythm thanks for the tip, im new to java, I will check the java naming conventions

Comment: Yeah, you can read the link I shared. Behind a HashMap there's a hashing algorith which queries with order = 1 as opposed to a list which queries with `order = n`. Try it out and let me know how that goes.

Comment: @markspace thanks for the reply, I'm gonna check Stax and XPath because I've never used them, I used DOM because it seemed easy to use and had all the functions I needed for the code im doing

Comment: XPath. Use the correct tool for the job.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Xpath does the job perfectly ! thanks for the suggestion, I've change DOM for Xpath, thanks to everyone for the help.